# Pass parameters into a file being called in a Grunt task?

Tags: javascript, io, gruntjs

I am using the command line to call the `grunt` command. I hard coded information to be run when this is executed and it works successfully. I am trying to use alias tasks to pass in numbers at the command line instead of hard coding. (The alias task isn't working yet, but that is not the main issue). In a task I execute another file via `src: path`. I want to pass the numbers from the command line into this program as well. Is that possible? How could I go about doing that?
The alias code I am working with I pulled from another question
[Pass params to an grunt task from an alias task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16239254/pass-params-to-an-grunt-task-from-an-alias-task):

```
grunt.registerTask('taskA', function(target) {
  var tasks = ['taskB', 'taskC'];
  if (target == null) {
    grunt.warn('taskA target must be specified, like taskA:001.');
  }
  grunt.task.run.apply(grunt.task, tasks.map(function(task) {
    return task + ':' + target;
  }));
});
```

The task that contains the code for the file that I am trying to pass parameter into looks like:

```
taskname: {
        //other code
        src: 'path.js'
      }
```

Can I pass data into the code that is at path.js

Edit: I am using Grunt in conjunction with Casper.js

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can pass parameter using [grunt.option](http://gruntjs.com/frequently-asked-questions#options).

You need to call your task with the parameter `... --your-param=1234` and in the task you can get the value by calling `grunt.option('your-param')`.

Comment: Is there a specific spot in the code where you place the grunt.option statement. I am using "var target = grunt.option('target');" and it tell me target does not exist.

Comment: Actually I was able to use the grunt.option, but now can I pass 'your-param' and use it inside `src: 'path.js`?

Comment: I forgot to tag you when I responded.